# Como usar array_diff con iteracion utilizando 2 querys

Tags: php, mysql

estoy tratando de encontrar con array_diff los valores(strings) que no estan presentes entre dos array resultantes de consultas mysql usando mysql_fetch_assoc para crear cada array.

Query 1

```
<?php
mysql_select_db($database_conn, $conn);
$query_est_lista = "SELECT localidades.estacion FROM localidades ORDER BY 
localidades.codigo ASC";
$est_lista = mysql_query($query_est_lista, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
$row_est_lista = mysql_fetch_assoc($est_lista);
$totalRows_est_lista = mysql_num_rows($est_lista);?>
```

Query 2

```
<?php
mysql_select_db($database_conn, $conn);
$query_est_entrada = sprintf("SELECT lluvias.estacion FROM lluvias WHERE 
lluvias.fecha LIKE %s", GetSQLValueString($today_est_entrada, "date"));
$est_entrada = mysql_query($query_est_entrada, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
$row_est_entrada = mysql_fetch_assoc($est_entrada);
$totalRows_est_entrada = mysql_num_rows($est_entrada);?>
```

Cuando trato de realizar la comprobacion asi...

```
  <?php 
 $arr= array_diff($row_est_lista,$row_est_entrada);
 foreach ($arr as $value) {
 echo $value.' '.'<br>';}?>
```

me devuelve el resultado esperado pero solo del primer valor en cada array y he tratado de iterar ambos arrays( usando do {} while()) pero no consigo que funcione correctamente. Por favor sugerir la forma correcta de iterar ambos arrays para encontrar todos los resultados.

Answer (score 0):

Las funciones mysql se consideran obsoletas, usa mysqli mejor.  El problema es que mysqli_fetch_assoc solo devuelve un row.  Lo que necesitas es mysqli_fetch_all asi:

```
<?php
mysqli_select_db($database_conn, $conn);
$query_est_lista = "SELECT localidades.estacion FROM localidades ORDER BY 
localidades.codigo ASC";
$est_lista = mysqli_query($query_est_lista, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
$row_est_lista = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($est_lista)) {
    $row_est_lista[] = $row;
}
$totalRows_est_lista = mysqli_num_rows($est_lista);?>
```

Comment: si, se que usar las antiguas func. mysql es riegoso pero la app ya esta totalmente diseñada asi, pudieras darme una solucion dentro de esta misma variante?

Comment: Podrias usar un loop `while ($row_est_lista = mysql_fetch_assoc($est_lista)) {`

Comment: ya use varios loops como ves en mi pregunta (use un do y un while) pero al parecer no lo he ordenado correctamente porque no me da los resultados bien, o me repite valores o no me muestra lo valores diferentes entre cada array. El problema es que segun la sintaxis de array_diff compara array1 con array2 y muestra los NO coincidentes, y en mi caso cada array tiene que iterarse hasta el final y no logro hacerlo correctamente.

Comment: ya edite mi respuesta, intentalo asi

Comment: alancfm, gracias pero me sigue dando errores, ahora Array to string conversion... cuando invoco el array_diff($row_est_lista,$row_est_entrada)

Answer (score 0):

Encontré otra solucion mas sencilla para lograr lo que queria, lo hice a traves de MySQL a traves de una consulta, aqui va por si alguien le hace falta algun dia.
SELECT estacion
FROM localidades
WHERE localidades.estacion NOT IN (SELECT estacion from lluvias WHERE lluvias.fecha LIKE today) 
eureka!